# When does an Entity Framework linq query return dynamic proxy types and when does it not?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to return a single item from my context as follows

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var person = context.People.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdatedDate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My context looks like:

```
public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
```

Why is it that the type of my person variable above is not `Person` but the dynamic proxy type such as `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies
.Person_5E43C6C196972BF0754973E48C9C941092D86818CD94005E9A759B70BF6E48E6`?

If I use `Find`, then I do get the type as `Person`. I want to return the top 1 record as ordered by the last update date and `OrderByDescending` / `FirstOrDefault` seemed like the most logical approach.

I realise I could turn off dynamic proxy generation but I don't think this is necessary.

Suppose my question is which linq methods cause the object to be returned as the type you might expect and which return the dynamic proxy type?

Comment: Update your question to "Which linq methods cause the object to be returned as the type you might expect and which return the dynamic proxy type?"

Comment: is it important to know this? the proxy object has nothing special, no members added automatically, it just overrides the virtual properties defined in your actual entity type to hook up some things.

Comment: I'm using automapper to then map to a dto. Trouble I'm having is that the mapping doesn't work when the type returned from the context is the dynamic proxy.

Comment: @obaylis So you can simply disable proxy creation.

Comment: I realise that. I was interested in why sometimes an object is returned as the dynamic proxy type (i.e. when I used FirstOrDefault) but other times it is not (i.e. when I used Find).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see in Entity Framework [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Objects/Internal/EntityProxyFactory.cs,cd132712e6e6df34), it is not related to any linq method. 
When creating the result, it checks if the `ProxyCreationEnabled` is true, then it checks that if a proxy can be created for type, then creates a proxy for it. And here is the rule for checking if can proxy type:

```
private static bool CanProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType)
{
    TypeAttributes access = ospaceEntityType.ClrType.Attributes & TypeAttributes.VisibilityMask;

    ConstructorInfo ctor = ospaceEntityType.ClrType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    bool accessableCtor = ctor != null && (((ctor.Attributes & MethodAttributes.MemberAccessMask) == MethodAttributes.Public) ||
                                            ((ctor.Attributes & MethodAttributes.MemberAccessMask) == MethodAttributes.Family) ||
                                            ((ctor.Attributes & MethodAttributes.MemberAccessMask) == MethodAttributes.FamORAssem));

    return (!(ospaceEntityType.Abstract ||
                ospaceEntityType.ClrType.IsSealed ||
                typeof(IEntityWithRelationships).IsAssignableFrom(ospaceEntityType.ClrType) ||
                !accessableCtor) &&
                access == TypeAttributes.Public);
}
```

Also from this msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx): Note that the EF will not create proxies for types where there is nothing for the proxy to do. This means that you can also avoid proxies by having types that are sealed and/or have no virtual properties.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did get dynamic proxies using FirstOrDefault but not with Find in my Linq query. It was using te same class in both cases (with virtual properties).